# Android: ListView tells me it's populated but not displaying items

Tags: java, android, listview, visibility, android-arrayadapter

So I've googled, and scoured SO for an answer to what I think is probably a ridiculous oversight, but here goes.

I have a `ListView` that I'm populating with an `ArrayAdapter` that I'm building out of a list of objects I'm using elsewhere in my application. I have checked via `getCount` that there are items in the adapter, both before and after I call `.setAdapter()`.  Nothing is showing up in my application however.

My main layout `res/layout/playlistview`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/playlist_screen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#80000000"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/playlistview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#206"
    android:background="#602" >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

(I set the colors so I could see what's going on more easily)

the `textview` for each item `res/layout/singlelistitem`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/single_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:padding="5dp" 
    android:background="#206">
</TextView>
```

and the code I use to populate it:

```
private ListView playlistView;

private void buildPlaylistView() {
playlistView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.playlistview);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singlelistitem, R.id.single_item, playlist.titlesAsArray());

playlistView.setAdapter(adapter);

playlistView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
((ArrayAdapter<String>)playlistView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`playlist.titlesAsArray()` does return `String[]` and it works.

I have both of the `.notifyDataSetChanged()` in there, since I found that on SO and gave it a try.

When I change the `android:layout_height` in the `ListView` object in my XML to `wrap_content`, I see only the opaque background that is in the `LinearLayout` that wraps it.  When I set the `ListView` `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`, the whole screen is `#206` (magentish).

When i check `getCount()` on the adapter before `setAdapter()` it says there are items.  When I check it after, from the view itself, it says there are the same number of items.  I'm totally lost on this one, but nothing is displayed.

Comment: I've just checked and it's working fine. I suspect that something else is messing with `playlistView` after the call to `buildPlaylistView();` and effectively resetting its content and/or adapter. It's just not in the code you've posted.

Comment: The only thing I do to the playlistView global is call bringToFront() and commenting it out did nothing.

I also set the visibility, invalidate to force redraw and perform some animations on a view connected to id/playlist_screen (the outer layout).

Comment: well... I don't know. upload the whole project if you can. without it it's just guessing. like I said - I've mocked `playlist.titlesAsArray()` to return static data, run it on an actual device and it worked fined. By fine I mean that it showed all the items in the adapter with proper colors, etc. You could also provide more hints - what API are you using? are you running this on emulator or device? everything can be of importance here...

Comment: Can't upload the whole project, it's for work so proprietary code and all that...  developing with minSdkVersion="8" and targetSdkVersion="17" on Android 4.2.  It's not working on my Samsung Continuum i400 with firmware 2.2.2/kernel 2.6.32.9, or the standard emulator using several api versions (which I don't trust regardless since they're bad about video anyhow, and it's a video-based app).  I've been with that setup for a while and everything else works that I'm doing.  Thanks for the dialogue on this.

Comment: don't have experience with Continuum but I don't suspect hardware since it appears that pretty much everything else is working. I totally understand limitations on posting the project, consider however posting http://sscce.org/ - cut *all* unnecessary code to the point where the list appears empty but it constitutes a *complete* Android project. with that I (and others) could run it on our devices and track this issue down.

Comment: Thanks for the replies andr, unfortunately I won't be able to post any more code, as per business decision.  This project has also been put on the back burner for now.  I took this app over and have argued for a full code review that I've been wanting time for and will now happen.  Hopefully this will uncover whatever strangeness is going on here.  Thanks again for your helpful input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing from `android:orientation="horizontal"` to `android:orientation="vertical"` this may fix.

Comment: Didn't work, but leads me to ask, can ListView's not be horizontal?  The rest of my app is horizontal, which is why that was in there that way (it plays videos in landscape format)

Comment: For listview we cannot set orientation, in the post I was mentioning about parent views orientation. I am doubting that objects are getting rendered but getting hidden due to layout.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've removed the orientation (and tried a dozen other things)

Comment: i have the same problem, but instead i am using listview inside RelativeLayout and also i have an emptyView in same parent which i hide it whenever i have more than 0 elements in adapter. Child items are renderer only on touch

Comment: My layout had a ScrollView as the parent view and this caused my ListView not to display. It would seem this is bad practice as ListView contains scrolling for free.